# MYSQL Trigger set datetime value using case statement

Tags: mysql, triggers, set, case

I'm using mysqlimport to do mass table inserts (replacing duplicates primary keys). Several tables have date time columns with records containing values '0000-00-00'. What I would like is a trigger which detects these '0000-00-00' values and replaces with '1950-01-01', otherwise keep the datetime value in the record (i.e. when it's not '0000-00-00').

I have tried the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_datetime BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW
CASE
WHEN date_col='0000-00-00' THEN SET date_col='1950-01-01';
END CASE
```

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Update attempt:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_datetime BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW
IF (NEW.date_col='0000-00-00') THEN
SET NEW.date_col='1950-01-01';
END IF;
```

Still getting an error in the SET portion.

**EDIT 2**

WORKING:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insert_check BEFORE INSERT ON ar
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.delivery_date='0000-00-00' THEN
        SET NEW.delivery_date='1950-01-01';
    END IF;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IF THEN` :

```
IF (NEW.date_col = '0000-00-00') THEN
  SET NEW.date_col='1950-01-01';
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_datetime BEFORE INSERT ON tbl 
FOR EACH ROW 
IF YEAR(NEW.date_col)=0 THEN
    SET NEW.date_col='1950-01-01 00:00:00'; 
END IF;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Accessing `OLD.` in `BEFORE INSERT` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, or need, to use 'case' then this should work:

```
SET NEW.date_col=CASE WHEN NEW.date_col='0000-00-00' THEN ='1950-01-01'
WHEN NEW.date_col='something else' THEN 'whatever'
ELSE 'default'
END CASE;
```