# How to create a Trigger within sql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have been trying to create a Trigger, however my attempts have been unsuccessful. I seem to be getting an error (#1064), which I have no solution for. Can somebody explain or demonstrate any faults in the syntax.

Let me specify:

I have delivery_id as primary key in delivery table,
I also have delivery_id as a foreign key in entry_log table.
By comparing both id's(if true), will return a text referring to the output of the bit (either 0 or 1)

```
    DELIMITER //
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS entry_trigger//

    CREATE TRIGGER entry_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON entry_log
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @xentry VARCHAR(45)
    DECLARE @inta bit

    SET @inta = SELECT allowed
    FROM delivery
    WHERE delivery.delivery_id = entry_log.delivery_id;


CASE
    when @inta = 0 then @xentry = 'Acces Denied'
    when @inta = 1 then @xentry = 'Acces Allowed'
END CASE

    INSERT INTO entry_log(entry_time,access_allowed) VALUES(now(),@xentry);

END
//
```

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming that you use MySQL. In the body of the trigger you use

```
WHERE delivery.delivery_id = entry_log.delivery_id;
```

I think you want to compare to the entry_log entry that the trigger is running on, right? In that case you must use this syntax:

```
WHERE delivery.delivery_id = NEW.delivery_id;
```

see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) for more examples.

**UPDATE**

I see that also you try to do an `INSERT INTO entry_log` within the TRIGGER. This will of course not work, because you would create an infinite recursive loop. Within the 
body of the trigger you can do unrelated table access, but not into the table you are inserting. You can change the values to be inserted by the trigger by setting `NEW.xyz = whatever`

**UPDATE 2**

I doubt, that your `CASE` statement is correct. At least it must end with `END CASE`. You can use `IF` here, since you don't have many cases to address. If you must use `CASE` this post might help you: [MYSQL Trigger set datetime value using case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419957/mysql-trigger-set-datetime-value-using-case-statement)

**UPDATE 3**
I am not sure, but I  think you need brackets around the variable setting statement. try this trigger definition:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS entry_trigger//

CREATE TRIGGER entry_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON entry_log
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @inta = (SELECT allowed
                 FROM delivery
                 WHERE delivery.delivery_id = NEW.delivery_id);

    SET NEW.access_allowed = @inta;
    SET NEW.entry_time = NOW();
END
//
```

Note, that this is written out of my head, so beware of syntax errors in my script.

Comment: Is that CASE statement also a problem?  Would it not be an IF statement, or have the CASE embedded in the subsequent INSERT?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just saw the first issue. There is more. I will address this in an update of my answer

Comment: I've changed it to END CASE : I still receive error on line 5 (#1064)

Comment: NO PROGRESS so far :(